# How can I use the apply() function for every column with their corresponding mean value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
  rowid  user_id  col_2   bias
  0        1      0       2.1
  1        2      2       2.5
  2        3      3       3.6
  3        1      0       2.8
  4        2      2       1.5
  5        3      3       3.2
```

Now I want to let 'bias' column be the mean value of corresponding user_id,just like that for one unique user_id:

```
 rowid  user_id  col_2   bias
  0        1      0       2.1
  3        1      0       2.8
```

to:

```
 rowid  user_id  col_2   bias
  0        1      0       2.45
  3        1      0       2.45
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby.transform`:

```
df['bias'] = df.bias.groupby(df.user_id).transform('mean')

df
#   rowid  user_id  col_2  bias
#0      0        1      0  2.45
#1      1        2      2  2.00
#2      2        3      3  3.40
#3      3        1      0  2.45
#4      4        2      2  2.00
#5      5        3      3  3.40
```